# Erro "could not load ssl library" usando delphi 7 e indy 10.0.52

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy-10

Estou utilizando `Delphi 7` e `indy 10.0.52`, tentando enviar um `json` com método `post` para uma `api` mas recebo sempre esta mensagem de erro:

> could not load ssl library

HA muito tempo atras já fiz este mesmo procedimento só que com a versão 9.0 do `indy`. A uns tempos tive a necessidade de atualizar o `indy` para a versão 10 e a partir deste momento não funcionou mais esse processo. Nas pesquisas que realizei, dizem que deveria colocar a versão correta para as `dlls`:

> libeay32
>   ssleay32.

Já testei varias versões porém sem sucesso com nenhuma, alguem saberia me dizer qual seria a versão da `dll` correta para essa versão do `indy`.

Comment: Utilizo a versão 10 da Indy, e ambas as dlls estão na versão 0.9.8.14

Answer (score 1):

Baixe diretamente dos links recomendados [nesta](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/ssl.en.aspx) pagina do projeto indy.

As mais atuais se encontram disponíveis aqui http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Aqui utilizamos a 0.9.8.14 a mesma recomendada pelo @VictorZanella.

Comment: No meu caso em específico eu estava tentando conectar uma API com RestDebugger no Win64x e ocorria o erro "rest request failed. Could not load ssl library"; Possivelmente as dlls estavam na versao 32, então eu baixei o link indicado pelo Diego: "http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/?C=M; O=A" e copiei as dlls para o diretório Bin do Delphi, onde se encontra o RestDebugger.exe

Comment: Só isso ai não resolve o problema.. não basta apenas as dlls, o meu erro continua também

Comment: @SérgioThiagoMendonça no geral esse erro é por conta de versões diferentes da dll, em primeiro lugar você deve fazer uma busca em todo seu computador por outras versões dela, tanto no system32 como na pasta windows e até mesmo na pasta bin do delphi. Se você der uma pesquisada por ordem de pesquisa dos diretórios vai ver que os apps em delphi e no windows no geral respeitam uma ordem de carga especifica, então se eles acham a dll com outra versão primeiro eles tentam carregar ela, gerando pra você o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Que eu me lembre, tive que instalar a biblioteca OpenSSL para Windows desse link https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Apenas as dlls não tinha resolvido.